# checking whether at least one value in a dataframe row is bigger than a given row-specific threshold

Tags: r, apply

this is my small reproducible example for the dataset I am working on:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- as.data.frame( cbind(a=1+round(runif(5), 2), b=round(rnorm(5), 2), high_cutoff=round(1+rnorm(5), 1)) )
```

The dataframe is:

```
     a     b   high_cutoff
   1.29 -1.69         2.3
   1.79  1.24        -0.7
   1.41 -0.11         2.7
   1.88 -0.12         1.5
   1.94  0.18         3.5
```

I am trying to check whether, by row, there is at least one value in the first two columns that is higher that the correpondig threshold in the third column
(say that I want to store a 1 if any of the two values is higher that the cutoff).

In the example, what I expect is to find is:

```
   higher_than_cutoff         
0
1
0 
1
0
```

I've been trying to use the following (wrong) code, and some variations of it, without much success:

```
higher_than_cutoff <- apply( dat[, c("a", "b")], 1, function(x) any(x > dat[, "high_cutoff"]) )
```

Can you please give some advice on how to proceed?
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible vectorized solution (if you fine with just `TRUE/FALSE` you can remove the `+` at the beginning)

```
+(rowSums(dat[-3L] > dat[, 3L]) > 0)
## [1] 0 1 0 1 0
```

If you insist on `apply`, you can do something like

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) +(any(x[-3] > x[3])))
## [1] 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks David! so it basically sums all the entries that, by row, are greater that the threshold, and if the number is > 0 it returns 1 (otherwise 0)? very clean, thanks

Comment: Yes. you can simplify it to just `rowSums(dat[-3L] > dat[, 3L]) > 0` if you fine with just `TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: perfect, thanks also for the clarification with apply

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
 as.integer(do.call(pmax,dat[-3]) > dat[,3])
 #[1] 0 1 0 1 0
```

Or

```
((max.col(dat))!=3)+0L
  #[1] 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: The `max.col` one is sneaky :) Very nice.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I haven't tested it with other cases.  If a row have the same values, may be I need to mention `max.col(dat, 'first')` or so depending on what the OP wanted

Answer (score 3):

The desired output can be obtained with

```
higher_than_cutoff <- apply(dat,1,function(x) (max(x[1],x[2])>x[3])*1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve, but desired output can be got without using `apply`, we just compare full column-vectors, no rowwise operations needed.

```
+(dat$a > dat$high_cutoff | dat$b > dat$high_cutoff)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0
```